# how can I shorten a postgresql query that uses same expression multiple times?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, full-outer-join

I would like to shorten this postgresql query so that I don't need to repeat "coalesce(gl.email, mc.email" several times...

```
select r.*,l.*, coalesce(r.email, l.email) 
from righttable r full outer join  lefttable l on r.email=l.email 
where coalesce(r.email, l.email) > 'h' 
order by coalesce(r.email, l.email) limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join with a `using` clause:

```
select *
from righttable r 
full outer join  lefttable l using(email)
where email > 'h' 
order by email 
limit 10
```

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html):

> The `USING` clause is a shorthand that allows you to take advantage of the specific situation where both sides of the join use the same name for the joining column(s).
>
> Furthermore, the output of `JOIN USING` suppresses redundant columns: there is no need to print both of the matched columns, since they must have equal values. While `JOIN ON` produces all columns from `T1` followed by all columns from `T2`, `JOIN USING` produces one output column for each of the listed column pairs (in the listed order), followed by any remaining columns from `T1`, followed by any remaining columns from `T2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me...

I repeat this select query consecutively.

```
select r.<field1>, r.<field2>, ..., l.<field1>, l.<field2>,...,coalesce(r.email, l.email) from righttable r full outer join  lefttable l on r.email=l.email where coalesce(r.email, l.email) > <last_read_email_address> order by coalesce(r.email, l.email) limit 10
```

In each consecutive request, I set the value of last_read_email_address to the final coalesced email address in the prior result set.

Simple.